# java8 convert string array to map(odd index is key, even index is value)

Tags: java, java-8

Now I have a String array,

```
String[] a= {"from","a@a.com","to","b@b.com","subject","hello b"};
```

from command line arguments.

I want to convert it to Map,

```
{"from":"a@a.com","to":"b@b.com","subject":"hello b"}
```

Does exist convenient manner in java8 to achieve this?
Now my way is

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i+=2) {
    String key = args[i].replaceFirst("-+", ""); //-from --> from
    map.put(key, args[i+1]);
}
```

Comment: This is not a code solving site. What have you tried so far?

Comment: According to me, you have to run a loop with `i=0;i<args.length;i+=2` and then adding `map.put(args[i],args[i+1])`

Comment: My take from the answers is: keep it as it is!

Answer (score 14):

You can use an `IntStream` to iterate on the indices of the array (which is required in order to process two elements of the array each time) and use the `Collectors.toMap` collector.

The `IntStream` will contain a corresponding index for each pair of elements of the input array. If the length of the array is odd, the last element will be ignored.

```
Map<String,String> map = 
    IntStream.range(0,a.length/2)
             .boxed()
             .collect(Collectors.toMap(i->a[2*i].replaceFirst("-+", ""),
                                       i->a[2*i+1]));
```

Comment: You forgot the `replaceFirst` code that strips leading `+` and `-`. Also, your ternary operator is identical to integer division, even or odd.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8 you can use `Stream.iterate` to divide list to sublists of 2 elements

```
    String[] a= {"from","a@a.com","to","b@b.com","subject","hello b"};

    Map<String, String> map = Stream.iterate(
        Arrays.asList(a), l -> l.subList(2, l.size()))
            .limit(a.length / 2)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                l -> l.get(0).replaceFirst("-+", ""),
                l -> l.get(1))
            );
```

Another recursive solution using simple `Iterator`

```
Map<String, String> map = buildMap(new HashMap<>(), Arrays.asList(a).iterator());

private static Map<String, String> buildMap(
        Map<String, String> map, Iterator<String> iterator) {
    if (iterator.hasNext()) {
        map.put(iterator.next().replaceFirst("-+", ""), iterator.next());
        createMap(map, iterator);
    }
    return map;
}
```

Comment: For what values of `a.length` does `(int) Math.floor(a.length / 2);` give you different values than simply `a.length / 2`?  Any that you care about?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this quite elegant with [Javaslang](http://javaslang.com/):

```
String[] a= {"from","a@a.com","to","b@b.com","subject","hello b"};

Map<String, String> map = Stream.of(a).grouped(2) // use javaslang.collection.Stream here
  .map(group -> group.toJavaArray(String.class))
  .toJavaStream() // this is the plain old java.util.Stream
  .collect(toMap(tuple -> tuple[0], tuple -> tuple[1]));
```

The `grouped` function groups your stream in groups of 2 elements. These can be transformed to string arrays and those can be the base of a `Map`. Probably Javaslang allows you to do even more elegant.

Answer (score -1):

The trick is to first join the string, then split it up into key/value *pairs*, then the task is simple:

```
Map<String,String> map = Arrays.stream(
    String.join(",", a)
          .split(",(?!(([^,]*,){2})*[^,]*$)"))
          .map(s -> s.split(","))
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s[0], s -> s[1]))
          ;
```